# How to get form input to appear as query params when div is click instead of button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, templates, parameters

I have an html form that is more or less the following

```
<form action="/results">
 <input name="q" type="text">
 <div>See results</div>
</form>
```

If I type something into the form, such as "my search" and press "enter" I'll be taken to the Results page with something like this: `mywebsite.com/results?q=my+search`. My problem is that I would like to get the same behavior when someone clicks "See results," which currently takes them to the Results page but without the params. I know using `<button>` instead of `<div>` would get me the results I need, but in this situation using `<button>` is not practical due to how all of the templates have been written.

Comment: Show your code that runs when the user clicks on the DIV.

Comment: You should be using `window.location = url` and put the query parameters into `url`.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate `?q=searchstring` to the URL when assigning to `window.location`.

```js
document.querySelector("#results").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let param = document.querySelector([name=q]).value;
  let url = `/results?q=${encodeURIComponent(param)}`;
  window.location = url;
}
```

```html
<form action="/results">
 <input name="q" type="text">
 <div id="results">See results</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use input type submit, try wrapping the it in the div as in this way:

```
<form action="/results">
    <input name="q" type="text">
    <div><input type="submit" value="See results" /></div>
</form>
```

If this not works for you, alternatively you can handle it using javascript as @Barmar answered above.